# Tkinter - Entry widget text to go to next line instead of continuing to the side

Tags: python, tkinter

so I made my entry widget for user input and made ipady larger. I thought this would make it so the text will automatically go to the next line but the text continues on. Is it possible to make the entry so that the text goes down instead and if it passes the length of ipady then create a scrollbar?

```
    def body(self, master):
#input fields for username and passwords
        Label(master, text="Name:").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W),
        Label(master, text="Date:").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        Label(master, text=":").grid(row=4)
        Label(master, text=":").grid(row=3, column=3)
        Label(master, text=":").grid(row=5)
        Label(master, text=":").grid(row=7)
        Label(master, text="L").grid(row=6)

        self.text = tk.StringVar()
        self.text.set(':')

        self.text1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.text1.set(':')

#input fields for tags
#Entry fields
        self.e1 = Entry(master)
        self.e2 = Entry(master)
        self.e3 = Entry(master, textvariable = self.text)
        self.e4 = Entry(master)
        self.e5 = Entry(master, textvariable = self.text1)
        self.e6 = Entry(master)
        self.e7 = Entry(master)

#Entry field Placement
        self.e1.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, ipadx=50)
        self.e2.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, ipadx=50)
        self.e3.grid(row=4, column=1, ipadx=150)
        self.e4.grid(row=4, column=3, ipadx=150, ipady=75)
        self.e5.grid(row=5, column=1, ipadx=150, ipadx=75)
        self.e6.grid(row=5, column=3, ipadx=150)
        self.e7.grid(row=6, column=1, ipadx=10, sticky=W)
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to make the entry so that the text goes down instead ...?

No, it is not. The `Entry` widget is specifically designed for single-line input. If you need multiple lines you need to use the `Text` widget.

Answer (score 1):

Entry widgents have only a single line. You'll have to use a 'Text' widget and print ('\n') for every entery letter.